# How to set object orientation in array modifier when following a curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm trying to create a marble run with an array and a curve modifier to create the track. But as you can see the rail won't hold the marble because of its rotation. The rail is following a Bezier curve.

[image]

How can I make the rail to be more parallel with the plan so the marble won't get ejected ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh this one's easy.
Just change the curve twist method to Z-Up.

[image]

Comment: Wow there is definitely an option for everything ! Thanks a lot, that did the trick :)

Comment: Yeah, this option appears to be specifically made for marble tracks :))